# Add behavior to Wicket Tab

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wicket

I have a wicket application on a page we have various forms for the same model split into separate tabs. What I need to do is whenever a tab is clicked check to see if a js variable `tabDirty` is set to true or false. If it is `true` I would launch a `confirm` prompt if okay then reset that form and move to the clicked tab. If cancel stay on that tab with keeping current changes.

I have this js for the warning nothing fancy

```
function warnOnChange(){
    if(tabDirty){
        decision = confirm('Leave?');
        if(decision){
            resetTab(); //sets tabDirty back to false
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I have a super simple wicket behavior

```
public class WarnChangePromptOnClickBehavior extends Behavior {

    @Override
    public void bind(Component component) {
        component.add(JQBehaviors.mouseClick(EditMerchant.WARN_ON_CHANGE));
    }
}
```

and that behavior is added to the AjaxFallBackLink

```
AjaxTabbedPanel<CustomAjaxTab> tabbedPanel = new AjaxTabbedPanel<CustomAjaxTab>("tabbedPanel", tabList, new Model<>(0)) {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected WebMarkupContainer newLink(final String linkId, final int index) {
        AjaxFallbackLink<Void> link = new AjaxFallbackLink<Void>(linkId) {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void onClick(final AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                TabbedPanel<CustomAjaxTab> selectedTab = setSelectedTab(index);
                CustomAjaxTab tab = tabList.get(index);
                if (target != null) {

                    tab.getPanel(linkId);

                    target.add(selectedTab);
                }
                onAjaxUpdate(target);
            }
        };

        link.add(new WarnChangePromptOnClickBehavior());
        return link;
    }

};
```

Current behavior with this is that if there is no change the tabs switch no prompt. If there is a change then I get the prompt. If okay `tabDirty` is reset and go to the next page clearing changes. Issue is that if I click cancel I still navigate to the next tab and lose changes. I know there is something in `onClick` I need to change but it is just not registering with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the appropriate way to do this but I solved my issue like this:

Same old js just slightly modified to return what the user chose:

```
function warnOnChange(){
    decision = true;
    if(tabDirty){
        decision = confirm('Leave?');
        if(decision){
            resetTab();
        }
    }
    return decision;
}
```

Dumped the whole behavior code although I still think it could be used just not sure at the moment...

So to make this all work on the link I override the `updateAjaxAttributes`of the link with a `precondition`:

```
AjaxTabbedPanel<CustomAjaxTab> tabbedPanel = new AjaxTabbedPanel<CustomAjaxTab>("tabbedPanel", tabList, new Model<>(0)) {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
protected WebMarkupContainer newLink(final String linkId, final int index) {
    AjaxFallbackLink<Void> link = new AjaxFallbackLink<Void>(linkId) {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        protected void updateAjaxAttributes( AjaxRequestAttributes attributes ) {
            super.updateAjaxAttributes( attributes );

            AjaxCallListener ajaxCallListener = new AjaxCallListener();
            //very important to use the "return" if not then nothing happens with the response
            ajaxCallListener.onPrecondition("return " + WARN_ON_CHANGE);

            attributes.getAjaxCallListeners().add( ajaxCallListener );
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(final AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            TabbedPanel<CustomAjaxTab> selectedTab = setSelectedTab(index);
            CustomAjaxTab tab = tabList.get(index);
            if (target != null) {

                tab.getPanel(linkId);

                target.add(selectedTab);
            }
            onAjaxUpdate(target);
        }
    };

    link.add(new WarnChangePromptOnClickBehavior());
    return link;
}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not that easy to intercept the JS event loop, especially when using Ajax requests.

Here is an approach that may do the job:

1. In `warnOnChange()` if `dirty` then call `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`. This will tell the browser to not follow the link / make an Ajax call. Then show the confirmation dialog as you do now.
2. If the user presses `Cancel` then there is nothing more to do
3. If the use confirms then set `dirty` to `false` and do `jQuery(event.target).triggerHandler(event.type)`, i.e. execute the same event (`click`) on the link. This time it won't be dirty and it will proceed with the Ajax call.

Comment: I am trying to call the event in the `warnOnChange` js function but keep getting console errors that it does not exist. Any chance you know a way to pass this in?